# How to integrate KCFinder with TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, tinymce

I am trying to integrate TinyMCE with KCFinder.  Can anyone help me figure out why the images upload file manager does not appears on my TinyMCE?

I already tried to install the file manager from https://kcfinder.sunhater.com/integrate

I have not been successful yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>    
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
<script src="js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>

<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>

<script>

tinyMCE.init({
//  ...
    file_browser_callback: function(field, url, type, win) {
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: '/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=tinymce4&field=' + field + '&type=' + type,
            title: 'KCFinder',
            width: 700,
            height: 500,
            inline: true,
            close_previous: false
        }, {
            window: win,
            input: field
        });
        return false;
    }
//  ...
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <textarea>Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</textarea>
</body>

</html>
```